# Xcode Pod build error while archiving the project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just migrated my old project swift 3 to swift 4 .When I build with simulator or real device its getting fine.But when I archive with Generic IOS device getting pod error. How to resolve this error.I am using Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61).

Comment: Have you changed your swift version from pods also??

Comment: Update pods with pod update ( be sure pod target is selected for swift 4). 

Don't migrate pods from Xcode tool

Comment: Please share the error.

Comment: issue resolved thanks for the quick response. deployment was 9.0 . I changed to 11.0 . But how it works with old target in simulator/Real device mode?